# Advanced search - include/exclude bounty questions

Tags: support, feature-request, bounty, search

Currently I use this [advanced search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3Amine%20is%3Aquestion%20answers%3A0%20score%3A-1..%20closed%3A0) to look for questions I'd like to answer.

However, I've never seen a question with an active bounty in this filter (even by [sorting by votes and going to page 3](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=Votes&q=intags%3Amine%20is%3Aquestion%20answers%3A0%20score%3A-1..%20closed%3A0) where [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749721/javascript-project-structure-component-architecture) should be listed, at least in my case, and I still can't see it)

1. Can we have the possibility to explicitly include or exclude
   questions with active bounty?
2. By using advanced search queries, can
   we have the active bounty questions included by default?

Answer (score 11):

Use the `hasnotice:` and `locked:` (thanks @BhargavRao) search options. This works because the bounty adds a so-called post notice, which are also used by locked posts so they need to be filtered out. The following query:

```
intags:mine is:question answers:0 score:-1.. closed:0 hasnotice:1 locked:0
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0+score%3A-1..+closed%3A0+hasnotice%3A1+locked%3A0) consists (almost) only of questions with an active bounty. For non-bountied questions, use `hasnotice:0` (and you can omit the `locked` option).

While there are other post notices (e.g. for questions related to 'current events'), they are almost never used on Stack Overflow. Therefore, this should do the trick for you.

Comment: I think there's a locked:0 option as well, using which you can exclude the locked posts

Comment: @BhargavRao great, thanks!

Comment: `is:q` is a shorthand for `is:question`

Comment: @Cœur correct, that's what I use as well. In this case, I was just modifying the OP's query.

Comment: It's a great alternative until we get a better way (like `hasbounty`)